Adding a description to the request body of Nest.js
I'm using Nest.js for the first time and migrating a legacy node.js API. I'm creating the first route to make sure this will preserve the OpenAPI spec capabilities. I've created the controller with one route that accepts a JSON body. The body class uses decorators from @nestjs/swagger, and I am able to see the schema show up in the Swatter UI when using the @Body decorator:
@Controller('my-api')
export class CertificatesController {
  @ApiOperation({ })
  @Post()
  async create(
    @Req() req: Request,
    @Res() res: Response,
    @Body() body: TheBody,
  ): Promise<Result> {
    //...
  }
}

However, one thing that the original API had was a description property for the body parameter, and there doesn't seem to be a way to add one to my TheBody class. I've tried adding an ApiBody decorator to the method, and that lets me add a description, but that shadows the schema of body, causing it to show the type as a string instead of the schema defined by TheBody.
How do you add a description to your body parameter in Nest.js without removing the type reflection provided by the @Body decorator?

It looks like the key is to add an @ApiBody() decorator to the route method, and you unfortunately have to also redudantly specify type for that. There isn't a way for the @Body() decorator in your function parameters to "merge" with your @ApiBody() properties.
import { ApiBody } from '@nestjs/swagger';

// ...

  @ApiBody({
    type: MySchemaClass,
    description: 'The description',
  })


npm i --save class-validator class-transformer (https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/validation)
npm install --save @nestjs/swagger (https://docs.nestjs.com/openapi/introduction)
Make TheBody Class Like this,
import { ApiProperty } from '@nestjs/swagger';
import { IsEmail, IsNotEmpty } from 'class-validator';

export class TheBody {
  @ApiProperty({
    description: 'The email of the user',
    example: 'email@gmail.com',
  })
  @IsEmail()
  email: string;

  @ApiProperty({
    description: 'The password of the user',
    example: 'password',
  })
  @IsNotEmpty()
  password: string;
}


That shows how to add descriptions to the schema properties but not to the body of the route.
